# How to show seconds on the clock in 22.04 LTS (Gnome)

Tags: gnome, 22.04, clock

Is there a way to get the clock (top bar) to show seconds?

I looked in the **Time & Date settings tab**, but there is still **nothing for seconds there**.

Answer (score 45):

**Without** even installing something like **gnome-tweaks**, you can simply enter this into a command prompt (Ctrl+Alt+T)

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface clock-show-seconds true
```